# How can I update longitude and latitude in a dictionnary

Tags: python

I have coordinates generated by a python program that puts all the possible coordinate combinations into a list for a given starting latitude cords and starting longitude cords.

```
startinglat = float(input("Input your starting Latitude Cords : "))
startinglong = float(input("Input your starting Longitude Cords : "))
rangeb = int(input("Input your cords range : "))
    
coordlistlat = [] # Latitude List
coordlistlong = [] # Longitude List
    
for i in range(rangeb) :
    startinglat += 0.000001
    coordlistlat.append(startinglat)
    startinglong -= 0.000001
    coordlistlong.append(startinglong)
```

I am trying to constantly refresh a dictionary and send a post request. Here are the contents of the dictionary:

```
data = {
    'latitude': '00.000000',
    'longitude': '-00.000000',
}
```

Here is what I've tried doing, but it keeps outputting the same data multiple times.

```
for i in coordlistlat:
    data['latitude']= i
    print(data['latitude'])
    time.sleep(3)

for z in coordlistlong:
    data['longitude'] =z
    print(data['longitude'])
    time.sleep(3)
```

Thank you in advance for any acquaintance you share with the community.

Comment: Testing your code, the `data` dictionary updates for me. Two thoughts: (1) When/where are you sending your POST request? and (2) The lat-lon coordinates generated in your first loop differ only slightly. Is the API able to output something with that kind of resolution?